# Why Spring Boot Batch job is running just one time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I'm using spring boot. I have a batch job which I've implemented with these classes :

My main class is :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.batch")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

}
```

My scheduler is :

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class JobScheduler {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    public void runJob() {
        SpringApplication.run(MyBatchConfig.class);
    }
}
```

and my batch configuration class is :

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyBatchConfig {

    @Value("${database.driver}")
    private String databaseDriver;
    @Value("${database.url}")
    private String databaseUrl;
    @Value("${database.username}")
    private String databaseUsername;
    @Value("${database.password}")
    private String databasePassword;

    @Bean
    public Job myJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step s) {
        Job job = jobs.get("myJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(s)
                .end()
                .build();
        return job;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step myStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<Account> reader,
                      ItemWriter<Person> writer, ItemProcessor<Account, Person> processor) {
        TaskletStep step = stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep")
                .<Account, Person>chunk(1)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
        step.setAllowStartIfComplete(true);
        return step;
    } ...
```

now, my problem is :

the scheduler works and it repeats every ten seconds,
but the job executes only on application startup(reader, processor and writer just execute once in startup) and it seems that

```
SpringApplication.run(MyBatchConfig.class);
```

has no effect on re-running the job.

what should I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Running Spring Boot like this will run the job and shutdown. That scheduler that reruns itself is certainly not going to do what you want.

Comment: I searched through web and many of tutorials are mentioning that SpringApplication.run(MyBatchConfig.class); will cause it to re-run. but in fact it doesn't. so what should I do?

Comment: Hi @PedramFarzaneh did you able to find the solution. Same problem I am stuck. When I run main class manually application works fine but by the scheduler, job is not triggering.

Comment: @Ayush I could solve the problem by the help of Sabir Khan's answer. It worked for me. Follow his answer, hopefully it may be helpful for your case too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I can think of,

1.You put this property in application.properties so your batch job doesn't start automatically by call of `SpringApplication.run(...)` from `main`method.

`spring.batch.job.enabled=false`

This will simply initialize your Spring Batch configuration and not actually start job.

2.Put annotation `@EnableScheduling`  on your Spring Boot Batch Job starting class i.e. on `Application`  class in your code.

3.Remove `@EnableScheduling` annotation from `JobScheduler` class and call , `jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters)` from `runJob()` instead of calling `SpringApplication.run(MyBatchConfig.class)`.

`JobLauncher` & `Job` beans can be auto wired to your scheduler class since context is already initialized.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Glad that issue is resolved, you can accept my answer if that solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `JobLauncher` bean and use that in scheduler for starting new job instances.

Comment: thanks luboskrnac, but this will raise an exception because already there is a job scheduled by @EnableBatchProcessing.